# ListView do Flutter não mostra os dados atualizados

Tags: flutter, listview

Bom dia galera. Estou com problemas quando fiz a atualização para o Flutter 2. Estou fazendo o curso da Alura e o projeto foi feito com o Flutter anterior. Ao cadastrar uma transferência no FormularioTransferencia, ao retornar para a ListaTransferencias, a ListView não mostra a transferência realizada. No projeto anterior, foi trocado o RaisedButton para ElevatedButton, pois o Raised foi deprecated. e tb foi trocado o uso do List() (deprecated) na inicialização do _transferencias para []. Vale salientar que quando estava usando o Flutter 1.12 roda normalmente, já no 2.0 acontece que a ListView não mostra as transferências. Realizei um debug e vi que a Lista está sendo populada normal, mas o que não atualiza e mostra o novo estado na tela de Transferências. Segue o código abaixo:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(ByteBankApp());

class ByteBankApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: ListaTransferencias(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class FormularioTransferencia extends StatelessWidget {
  final TextEditingController _controladorCampoNumeroConta =
      TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _controladorCampoValor = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Criando Transferência'),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Editor(
                controlador: _controladorCampoNumeroConta,
                rotulo: 'Número da conta',
                dica: '0000'),
            Editor(
                controlador: _controladorCampoValor,
                rotulo: 'Valor',
                dica: '0.00',
                icone: Icons.monetization_on),
            TextButton(
              style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
              ),
              onPressed: () => _criaTransferencia(context),
              child: Text(
                'Confirmar',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ));
  }

  void _criaTransferencia(BuildContext context) {
    final int numeroConta = int.tryParse(_controladorCampoNumeroConta.text);
    final double valor = double.tryParse(_controladorCampoValor.text);
    if (numeroConta != null && valor != null) {
      final transferenciaCriada = Transferencia(valor, numeroConta);
      debugPrint('Criando transferência');

      Navigator.pop(context, transferenciaCriada);
    }
  }
}

class Editor extends StatelessWidget {
  final TextEditingController controlador;
  final String rotulo;
  final String dica;
  final IconData icone;

  Editor({
    this.controlador,
    this.rotulo,
    this.dica,
    this.icone,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
      child: TextField(
        controller: controlador,
        style: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 24.0,
        ),
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          icon: icone != null ? Icon(icone) : null,
          labelText: rotulo,
          hintText: dica,
        ),
        keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ListaTransferencias extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<Transferencia> _transferencias = [];

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return ListaTransferenciasState();
  }
}

class ListaTransferenciasState extends State<ListaTransferencias> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {        
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Transferências'),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: widget._transferencias.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, indice) {
          final transferencia = widget._transferencias[indice];
          return ItemTransferencia(transferencia);
        },
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
        onPressed: () {
          final Future<Transferencia> future =
              Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
            return FormularioTransferencia();
          }));
          future.then((tranferenciaRecebida) {
            debugPrint('chegou no then do future');
            debugPrint('$tranferenciaRecebida');
            widget._transferencias.add(tranferenciaRecebida);
          });
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ItemTransferencia extends StatelessWidget {
  final Transferencia _transferencia;

  ItemTransferencia(this._transferencia);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      child: ListTile(
        leading: Icon(Icons.monetization_on),
        title: Text(_transferencia.valor.toString()),
        subtitle: Text(_transferencia.numeroConta.toString()),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Transferencia {
  final double valor;
  final int numeroConta;

  Transferencia(this.valor, this.numeroConta);

  @override
  String toString() =>
      'A Transferencia foi de $valor na Conta de número $numeroConta)';
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você está colocando algumas coisas nos locais errados...

Os objetos que podem sofrer alterações, devem ficar dentro do *State* quando você está utilizando *StatefulWidget*, então faça as seguintes modificações:

```
class ListaTransferencias extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return ListaTransferenciasState();
  }
}

class ListaTransferenciasState extends State<ListaTransferencias> {
  final List<Transferencia> _transferencias = [];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {        
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Transferências'),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: _transferencias.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, indice) {
          final transferencia = _transferencias[indice];
          return ItemTransferencia(transferencia);
        },
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
        onPressed: () {
          final Future<Transferencia> future =
              Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
            return FormularioTransferencia();
          }));
          future.then((tranferenciaRecebida) {
            debugPrint('chegou no then do future');
            debugPrint('$tranferenciaRecebida');
            setState(() {
              _transferencias.add(tranferenciaRecebida);
            }
          });
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

### Explicação

A propriedade _*transferencias* deve ficar dentro do *ListaTransferenciasState* para que ela possa ter seu estado atualizado.

No toque do FAB, ao sair da tela Formulário é preciso que atualize o estado do objeto _*transferencia* para surgir efeitos visuais na tela, sendo assim é preciso usar o `setState((){})`.

Comment: Obrigado Matheus Ribeiro. Eh isso mesmo. Com sua implementação funcionou direitinho! Excelente!